# How to show value of Count Function on my template. Django

Tags: django, django-views

I would like to show the total number of employees registered in my database. Using the count function.

My views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')

def return_total_employees(request):
    return_total = Employees.objects.aggregate(total=Count('EmployeeCard'))[
            'total'
        ]
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'return_total ': return_total })
```

My template:

```
<h1> {{ view.return_total_employees }} </h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dict` you're returning in the render function is called `context`. You can access the value of returned context in your template like this

`{{return_total}}`